# Applying onClick() ListView showing XML

Tags: c#

Is it possible to applying some sort of "onClick" event on the XML nodes? With the following:

```
<tables>
   <test>
     <code>123</code>
   </test>
   <test>
     <code>1234</code>
   </test>
</tables>
```

If I read the XML file into my project and display it in a ListView, can I add an "on click" method to 123?

```
private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   testBox1.Text = "test";
}
```

When i try the onClick method above it displays test when i click on 123 and 1234, is their a way to specify the node you want the onClick method to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since XML is based in a tree-like structure, I wouldn't use a ListView. I'd use a Tree View instead.

You can set "On CLick" methods to those. Not sure what you're trying to do exactly though.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview

ADDED: TO answer your other question - you will probably want to see the listview's 'selected item' or 'selected item index' and write the code there. Its the same onClick event, just check what was selected.

Added 2:

```
private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  testBox1.Text = listView1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```